# Multilanguage support for site problem

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have couple labels and tabs in my site and I need to make possible to user to change language of that labels and tabs. How to achieve this ? Is there something already done in Dojo or plain Javascript for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is mechanism of internalization and localization in Dojo. You can read documentation about [dojo.i18n](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/quickstart/internationalization/index.html#quickstart-internationalization-index)

Answer (score 1):

you can use css classes to specify what multi language content an element must support
see http://jsfiddle.net/AJKTx/